# Using jQuery to link to a page and then jump to a specific header

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, anchor

I have a client site that has a community events page. On that page, events are generated and put out one by one like this:

```
<div class="event-info">
    <h5>This is an event</h5>
    <span class="date">December 25, 2013</span>
    <p class="details"></p>
</div>
```

They want a link on the homepage that goes to this one Christmas event, which will eventually start to move down the page. The only way to really find that block is by the contents of the `<H5>`. A classic anchor link would do the trick, but I can't add them to the `<div class="event-info" />` block. The homepage link has to go to this page and then jump down to the necessary `<div class="event-info" />`.

jQuery or vanilla javascript are all I have to work with. I have one .js file that I can add to, and of course the html/javascript of the link itself on the homepage. I can't manipulate the existing HTML of the pages (content is dynamic - I add new stuff to it), and I have no access to the backend .NET framework.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**something like this?**

jquery:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
if (hash==='#xmas') {
    var xmas = $('.date:contains("December 25")').parent('.event-info').offset().top;
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: xmas}, 500);
}
```

You just add `#xmas` to end of the page url, like: http://fiddle.jshell.net/filever10/afK7M/show/light/#xmas

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/afK7M/

Comment: Yes, I've since implemented it. Thank you!